# Insert large JSON data from web service into mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I am trying to insert multiple records to MongoDB at once which is return by web service in JSON format.

But I got the following **error :**

```
    INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 0, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=3, electionId=null, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=545196}
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [_id]
        at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:168)
        at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList._getInt(BasicBSONList.java:160)
        at org.bson.types.BasicBSONList.get(BasicBSONList.java:105)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:309)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:284)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:250)
        at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:187)
        at santosh.GoPharmaTest.main(GoPharmaTest.java:80)
```

I have used the following code , Please suggest what I do to get the result ?

```
        package santosh;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;

        import com.mongodb.DB;
        import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
        import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
        import com.mongodb.DBObject;
        import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
        import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

        public class GoPharmaTest {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String response="";
                MongoClient mongoclient=new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
                DB db = mongoclient.getDB("admin");
                DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("product");

                String url = "user web service";

                URL obj;
                try {

                    obj = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

                    // optional default is GET
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    //add request header
                    //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

                    //int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                    //StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response+=inputLine;
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(response);
                collection.insert(dbObject);

                DBCursor cursorDoc = collection.find();
                while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(cursorDoc.next());
                }
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BasicDBList** can't be used to do inserts of multiple documents, it's only used for arrays inside a single document. To do a **bulk insert**, you need to pass an array of DBObjects into the insert method instead.

as per [java doc](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) the insert() can accept either single DBObject or an array or List of them.

So, in order to save, you need to convert your JSON array into an array/List of DBObjects, or save each array's item

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I want add documents using mongodb version 3.0.Using class MongoCollection so how it is used ?